# How to compile/install/configure simple-realtime-server (SRS) on Windows

Tags: windows, simple-realtime-server

I have searched just about everywhere, and all the guides I can find in regards to SRS point to how you set it up using Linux.
According to the tags I have seens SRS also supports Windows.
Can anyone do a complete guide for it for Windows?

Regards
SnowmanDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, it is still a feature branch at [feature/windows](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/tree/feature/windows), which is built by Cygwin64, so you could use this branch to build SRS for Windows.

About build, please read [SRS#2532](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/2532#build), the installer is also available on [SRS 5.0+ tags](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/releases?q=v5&expanded=true), as an assert of each version like `SRS-Windows-x86_64-5.0.19-setup.exe`.

> Note that it's a feature branch and not stable, and it's only supported by SRS 5.0 or higher.